# Mysql: how do I make an exact working copy of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am working on a restructuring of a legacy database and its associated applications. To keep old and new working in parallel I have created a development database and copied the tables of interest to it, e.g.

```
create database devdb;

drop table if exists devdb.tab1;
CREATE TABLE devdb.tab1 like working.tab1;
insert into devdb.tab1 select * from working.tab1;
```

Having done this I notice that triggers affecting tab1 have not been copied over. Is there any way in which I can produce a working copy of tab1, i.e. data, permissions, triggers, everything?

Answer (score 0):

There is a quicker way to both recreate the structure and import datas (albeit you lose your indexes ;)):

```
 create table devdb.tab1 select * from working.tab1;
```

For the triggers and friends, you will have to query in information_schemas

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, kind of obvious in hindsight but it would appear that dumping the tables via mysqldump and loading those dumps in the new database restores triggers (and I would hope any other relevant information).

Shame as I had wanted to do the whole process via the DbVisualizer database manager. You learn something everything day ...

Answer (score 0):

Note that the "create table x select * from y" syntax will **not** create an exact working copy of the table, even if you're not concerned about triggers an whatnot.  The new table will:

- Use the default MyISAM table type (even if the parent table is InnoDB)
- Default to the Latin1 character set (even if the parent table is UTF-8)
- May wipe out the values of auto_incremented fields and replace them with 0 (depends on table structure but really nasty if it happens to you)

Comment: I just issued the command `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_table SELECT * FROM old_table1, old_table2 WHERE FALSE` and `information_schema.tables` shows its engine as being `innodb`.